# Burn down chart in wave analytics

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein

Is there any way with which we can create "Burn Down" chart in wave analytics?

I am not getting any clue about that. Please tell if it can be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Line chart type and play with its properties, you can change the Axis mode to **Dual Axis** to make it like a burn down chart. Check also the combo chart if you want columns as well.

[image: Dualaxis property]